# getting mouse coordinates in React and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to get the relative coordinates of the mouse in an element in React using jQuery.

My code doesn't seem to be working and there are no console errors.

code:

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets.css" >
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="ja.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Where's Waldo</title>
  </head>

    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

ja.js (jQuery function)

```
jQuery(function($) {
 var x,y;
 $("#waldo1").mousemove(function(event) {
     var offset = $(this).offset();
     x = event.pageX- offset.left;
     y = event.pageY- offset.top;
     $("#coords").html("(X: "+x+", Y: "+y+")");
 });
});
```

component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Timer from './timer'

class Level1 extends Component {

    render () {
      return (
      <div>
      <div id="gameBoard">
        <img id="waldo1" src={require('../images/waldo1(1).jpg')} alt="waldo"/>
      </div>
      <h2 id="coords"></h2>
      <Timer start={Date.now()}/>
      </div>
        ) // return
      } // render
    } //component

    export default Level1
```

I hear jQuery doen't play nice with react. Is my syntax correct or is there a better way entirely?

Thank you.

Comment: e.syntheticEvent from an onMouseMove react callback helped me

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the issue is that react has not rendered your component to the DOM when jQuery tries to attach the event listener.

You don't need jQuery to do this at all, a better approach is to use the React events:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  }

  _onMouseMove(e) {
    this.setState({ x: e.screenX, y: e.screenY });
  }

  render() {
    const { x, y } = this.state;
    return <div onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove.bind(this)}>
      <h1>Mouse coordinates: { x } { y }</h1>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Example pen: https://codepen.io/CarlosEME/pen/XWWpVMp

Comment: Carlos. Thank you for your answer. How would I use this to get coordinates relative to the #waldo division. Does react have an offset ()?

Comment: Yes, you can can get the DOM element using `nativeEvent` and use `e.nativeEvent.offsetX` and `e.nativeEvent.offsetY`

Comment: Pardon my stupidity, but I couldn't find this in the documentation (a user posted a link for this below). How would I grab the element? The closest thing I see is using react dom and using findDOMNode or something like that. Thank you very much. I'll accept this as an answer shortly.

Comment: Have a look a `refs` in React, you can give any component a reference: `<div ref="element" />` and then you can do `const elem = this.refs.element` to get the DOM Element itself. (In older versions of React you need to use `this.refs.element.getDOMNode()`). The pen I posted has an example on how to do that.

Comment: When I put `onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove.bind(this)}` on the parent div for the component, only when the mouse moves in the h1 element does it update the state, when I try putting the code on the img tag which is a child of the main div, the state doesn't change at all and seemingly it doesn't know that an event handler exists. How do i fix this so movement in the img renders a new x y coordinate.

Comment: @Quesurfin I'm not sure on what's not working for you, if you could post an example pen it would be easier to debug. Look, I updated the pen moving the event handler to an image: http://codepen.io/CarlosEME/pen/ZLVbWp

Comment: Carlos, you've been amazing. It works in codepen. No need to share. Is it possible its an issue related to my css properties?

Comment: It IS a css issue thank you so much! You should have a 'tip button' lol

Comment: Has anyone ran across a similar example for React > 15?

Comment: @Slbox I'm wondering what didn't work for you? I got this same example to work in the latest version of React. Yes, you can rewrite it using stateless components and hooks but it's the same idea.

Comment: Here's the same example with React 16 https://codepen.io/CarlosEME/pen/XWWpVMp

Comment: It is bad practice to call `bind` method on every render! `this._onMouseMove.bind(this)` have to be moved to the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ClassCursorPosition extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
  }

  logMousePosition = e => {
    this.setState({
      x: e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY
    });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.logMousePosition);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        X- {this.state.x} Y - {this.state.y}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Actually there are three things you can consider, here I mention clientX, clientY you can search for **pageX, pageY** and **secrrenX, screenY** as well.

pageX, pageY => depends on mouse position according to page.( scrollable page)

screenX, screenY => depends on mouse position according to screen ( height and width of different screens)

Answer (score 3):

This is almost exactly the same answer with Carlos Martinez but with functional component and hooks:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [coord, setCoord] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    setCoord({ x: e.screenX, y: e.screenY });
  };

  return (
    <div className="main" onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
      <h1>
        Mouse coordinates: {coord.x} {coord.y}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/artidata/mouse-coordinate

Answer (score 0):

The issue (and the reason jQuery and react don't go well together) is likely that react has not rendered to the DOM that element by the time jQuery is trying to attach the event listener.

You should look at attaching event listeners using reacts methods. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var x, y;
    $(document).on('mousemove', '#waldo', function (event) {
        x = event.pageX;
        y = event.pageY;
        $("#coords").html("(X: " + x + ", Y: " + y + ")");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why the heck was this downvoted? Being that this uses a deferred reference, this is guaranteed to work as it will attach to elements, even if they aren't in the DOM as the time the bind occurs. Based on ops question, this is a valid solution.

Comment: Didn't downvote - but it is introducing a React anti pattern. There should be no need to rely on jQuery when using React. Does it work? Sure. Is it right? Not so much

Comment: I would normally agree with those who downvoted but the OP specifically asks about jQuery so downvoting this answer feels like shooting the messenger.