# REACT: How could we detect user click on canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, canvas, click

Hello and thank you for reading this question.

I had an use case in which I needed to detect mouse coordinates on canvas, and thank you to @Carlos Martinez : [getting mouse coordinates in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182481/getting-mouse-coordinates-in-react) it works as expected.

I tryed to go further and detect if user clicks on canvas and then put on a h2 it, using state, and log it; and here is the code I have tryed:

```
import React from 'react';


class Canvas extends React.Component {
    //A canvas to display images with a title


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {x: 0, y: 0, inside: ''};

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    _onMouseMove(e) {
        this.setState({x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX, y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        console.log('INSIDE');
        this.setState({inside: 'inside'});
    }

    render() {

        const {x, y, inside} = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="previewComponent">
                <div className="imgPreview">
                    {this.props.title}
                    <img src={this.props.image} alt="" onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove.bind(this)}
                         onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
                    <h1>Mouse coordinates: {x} {y}</h1>
                    <h2>Inside?: {inside}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export {Canvas};
```

I expected that it would log it just once, and also put it on h2 tag.

However, unexpectedly it logs INSIDE, and then in addition logs two INSIDE:

```
INSIDE
2 Canvas.js:29 INSIDE
```

Could you explain me this behaviour? Also, it would be appreciated some tips to fix it and just print one log per click!

EDIT:

I have tried @Or B answer and I understood it however it looks like it stills showing the same behaviour, 3 logs of INSIDE instead of one:

[image]

The code is:

```
 handleClick(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('INSIDE');
        this.setState({inside: 'inside'});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to event propagation and the fact that you're listening to `click` events on the entire document.

Clicking on the `<img>` not only generates a `click` event for the image, but also for the two wrapping `<div>` elements. These two are captured by the document, which is why it's being logged two more times. If you log `e.target` you could see which element triggered the event.

In order to prevent it from propagating, use `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
handleClick(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('INSIDE');
        this.setState({inside: 'inside'});
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Or B your answer helped me, I have edited the post, because the behaviour stills equal.

Comment: @Enoy What's being logged if you print `e.target`? Is there a particular reason you're listening to events for the entire document?

Answer (score 1):

This is because click handler is being called twice. Once by the canvas `onClick` component and the second time by the click handler inside the componentWillMount function. Also, the `componentWillMount` function listens to the clicks on the entire document because of the `document.addEventListener` part. I would simply use the `componentWillMount` to set states.

Remove the `document.addEventListener` part and it should be good to go.