How to position x position under mouse cursor in react-tooltip?
I currently implemented tooltips using the react-tooltip library.
The problem here is that the tooltip must be positioned below the mouse cursor, not at the start point of the element.
I used the position option, but this doesn't work for me because I have to use the y-axis unconditionally.
Do you know how to use the value applied in react-tooltip for the y-axis and specify only the x-axis value?
function App() {
  const arr = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i);
  const [tooltipPosition, setTooltipPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  const handleMouseEnter = (event) => {
    const { pageX, pageY } = event;
    setTooltipPosition({ x: pageX, y: pageY });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Tooltip
        id='tooltip'
        positionStrategy='fixed'
        position={tooltipPosition}
        clickable
      />
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '10px' }}>
        {arr.map((item) => (
          <div
            data-tooltip-id='tooltip'
            data-tooltip-content='Hello world!'
            data-tooltip-place='bottom-start'
            onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
            style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100px', backgroundColor: 'gray' }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

When applied in this way, the tooltip should be facing upwards, but the problem is that it is facing downwards. Therefore, I want to set the value specified in react-tooltip for the y-axis and only specify the value for the x-axis. Is there a way to do this?
My current situation:


So you want the tooltip to folllow the mouse?

Instead of following the element, I want it to be positioned under the mouse cursor when hovering over the element.
For example, when an element is 200px and you hover over the center of the element, a tooltip should appear below the center.

Your code currently only tracks the mouse position once upon entering the element. So the position for the tooltip is always the border of the element, where the mouse entered. For more details on the behavior of the mouseenter-event, check MDN - mouseenter event.
What you need is some logic which keeps track of the mouse position.
Check this answer for a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71640760/27893855
Applying the information from that answer to your code you end up with this:
function App() {
  const arr = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i);
  const [tooltipPosition, setTooltipPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  const handleMouseMove(e) {
     const { screenX, screenY } = event;
     setTooltipPosition({ x: screenX, y: screenY });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Tooltip
        id='tooltip'
        positionStrategy='fixed'
        position={tooltipPosition}
        clickable
      />
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '10px' }}>
        {arr.map((item) => (
          <div
            data-tooltip-id='tooltip'
            data-tooltip-content='Hello world!'
            data-tooltip-place='bottom-start'
            onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
            style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100px', backgroundColor: 'gray' }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

This code will allow the tooltip position to be updated for as long as the user is hovering the element, using the mousemove-event. For more information on the mousemove-event, check MDN - mousemove event
You might need to add some code for hiding the tooltip when the user no longer hovers the element at all, though, but since the question does not focus on this, I did not add logic for it. If you want to do something like that, take a look at the MDN - mouseleave event.
